# Correct way to write a LINQ or Lambda to retrieve items with a matching supplier ID

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Given the following classes

Product
- int ProductID
- Supplier[] Suppliers
...

Supplier
- int SupplierID
- string SupplierName
...

If I have an array of 1000 products, and each product can contain multiple suppliers, how would I get supplier ID [X] from the array of Products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var suppliers = 
    from product in products
    from supplier in product.Suppliers
    where supplier.SupplierID == X
    select supplier;
```

Or use the extension method equivalent:

```
var suppliers = 
    products.SelectMany(p => p.Suppliers).Where(s => s.SupplierID == X);
```

Comment: You may want to add a Distinct around that.

Comment: If Suppliers has distinct `SupplierId` you might want to simply change `Where()` with `Single()` in your extension method.

Comment: You may want to call .ToList() (or .ToArray, or make suppliers a List<T>), to get eager evaluation. Particularly (potentially...) if you're dealing with an external data source and binning the connections, etc